# Problems using BaseX GUI

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, basex, xbrl

I am trying to *navigate* through an `instance` by using *XPath*. I am providing below an excerpt of the [original](http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/874214/000087421414000008/ann-20140201.xml) `instance`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<xbrli:xbrl xmlns:ann="http://www.anninc.com/20140201" 
            xmlns:dei="http://xbrl.sec.gov/dei/2013-01-31" 
            xmlns:iso4217="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/iso4217" 
            xmlns:link="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase" 
            xmlns:us-gaap="http://fasb.org/us-gaap/2013-01-31" 
            xmlns:xbrldi="http://xbrl.org/2006/xbrldi" 
            xmlns:xbrli="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance" 
            xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <link:schemaRef xlink:href="ann-20140201.xsd" 
                  xlink:type="simple" />
  <xbrli:context id="FD2011Q4YTD">
    <xbrli:entity>
      <xbrli:identifier scheme="http://www.sec.gov/CIK"
         >0000874214</xbrli:identifier>
    </xbrli:entity>
    <xbrli:period>
      <xbrli:startDate>2011-01-30</xbrli:startDate>
      <xbrli:endDate>2012-01-28</xbrli:endDate>
    </xbrli:period>
  </xbrli:context>
  <xbrli:context id="FD2011Q4YTD_ann_EarningsPerShareReconciliationAxis_ann_EarningsPerShareBasic.Member">
    <xbrli:entity>
```

I am aware that the `root element` has a `namespace` inside. I am using *BaseX GUI*. According to previous help my `root element` is `{http://xbrl.org/2003/instance}xbrl`!

However when i am trying it on an *XPath expression* like this:

```
xquery doc("ann-20140201.xml")//{http://xbrl.org/2003/instance}xbrl
```

and i hit *Execute Query* i am getting:

```
Error:
Stopped at C:/Users/Μαρίνος/Desktop/ann-20140201.xml, 1/6:
[XPST0003] Processing instruction has illegal name: 'xml'.
```

What am i doing wrong? Also i have been advised to use:

```
declare namespace xbrli=http://xbrl.org/2003/instance;
```

I am inputting this command from the *GUI* and i `input` the `command` here (do i input the *declaration command* here?):

[image]

BUT i am still getting the same `error` message as seen above. What must i do with the `illegal name: xml`?

**EDIT_1**

[wst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1226554/wst) says use `Q` with Clark Notation:

```
xquery doc("ann-20140201.xml")//Q{http://xbrl.org/2003/instance}xbrl
```

--> If i hit *run* it *executes* with no error. However instead of getting the `root element` in the `Result` pane on *BaseX* as i get it with this command:

```
XQUERY doc("ann-20140201.xml")//*
```

I get nothing; why that? Also how do i declare a namespace?

Comment: If you're going to provide a document excerpt, make it complete and testable -- something we can actually run ourselves, and that you've tested to guarantee will exhibit the same problem.

Comment: I have posted in a link the original instance (http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1009672/000119312514065056/crr-20131231.xml) in my SO post

Comment: There are no processing instruction in that file *at all*. I have trouble believing that it's the same file giving you an error about processing instructions with illegal names.

Comment: Isn't that a processing instruction : `xquery doc("ann-20140201.xml")//Q{http://xbrl.org/2003/instance}xbrl` ? what have i made wrong?

Comment: No, a processing instruction in XML is a node that starts with `<?`. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_Instruction. For instance, `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" value="css.xsl"/>`

Comment: I am sorry sir but isnt that the processing instruction (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>`)? --in the first line.

Comment: `<?xml` is a special case thing that must be only at the very, *very* beginning of the file. If you have one anywhere else -- even a single character before that line -- that would be the cause of your bug.

Comment: With respect to the GUI, by the way -- if you want to enter declarations, use the full query window, not the quick search bar.

Comment: Oh indeed in the link there is no `<xml` however when i download it and save as `xml` i have `<xml` in my first line. I open it with Notepad++

Comment: Hmm. US-ASCII is a somewhat unfortunate choice of encodings. Fortunately, UTF-8 is compatible with it, so you should be able to remove that line entirely, fall back to the defaults, and see if doing so changes things. If it does, you might consider posting to the BaseX mailing list.

Comment: I remove the US-ASCII entirelly and i get `[FODC0002] "C:/Users/Μαρίνος/Desktop/ann-20140201.xml" (Line 1): A pseudo attribute name is expected.` (Could you please tell me where is the full query window i am googling to find it ;-))

Comment: My first line now is: `<?xml version="1.0">`

Comment: By "remove that line entirely", I meant the whole line, not just the encoding declaration.

Comment: i have removed the line entirely and i am getting: `[XPST0003] Comparison is incomplete.` when i enter: `declare namespace xbrli=http://xbrl.org/2003/instance;`

Comment: If that's the *only* thing you're entering, yes, it *is* incomplete. Put your query in the same window.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55449/discussion-between-exoticbirdsmerchant-and-charles-duffy).

Comment: Could you please tell me where is the full query window? I cant seem to find it :P (sorry)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter the following in the editor window and press "run":

```
declare namespace xbrli="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance";

http:send-request(
  <http:request method='get'/>,
  'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/874214/000087421414000008/ann-20140201.xml'
)[2]/xbrli:xbrl
```

The database is able to retrieve the original document over HTTP and query the root element from it without issue.

More locally, the following works perfectly as well (after importing the document as a database):

```
declare namespace xbrli="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance";
doc("ann-20140201")/xbrli:xbrl
```

I notice that your namespace declaration in the question doesn't have question marks -- those are important.

I also have no trouble getting a result from a QName-based query:

```
doc("ann-20140201")/Q{http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance}xbrl
```

Comment: Wow i think it works.... strange you put the first command (declare...) in the place where the xml was

Comment: Thanks. Just a last wrinkle if i may. I was under the impression (as a very new user) that at the editor window we only put the xml to be queried and not commands...doesn't this use of the editor to put commands create ambiguity?(just asking)

Comment: No, the editor window is not where you put the XML to be queried in normal/typical workflows. Generally, that content should be stored in the database (as with the "create database" command).

Comment: This whole tutoring has been a ton of gold for me thank you! God Bless!

Answer (score 1):

I think in order to query using Clark Notation, you need to prefix with `Q`:

```
xquery doc("ann-20140201.xml")//Q{http://xbrl.org/2003/instance}xbrl
```

Answer (score 1):

The processor shouldn't see the XML declaration (`<?xml...?>`) as a processing instruction.

Make sure you don't have any whitespace, including linebreaks, before the declaration. It needs to be the very first thing in the file.

Comment: 1. I do not have any whitespace here: `declare namespace xbrli=http://xbrl.org/2003/instance;` the first character is the letter d in the command no whitespace.

Comment: 2. In the top of the `XML` excerpt there is in the first line: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>`

Comment: @ExoticBirdsMerchant - #2 was what I meant. The only time I've ever seen this error is when there has been whitespace before the declaration. If you don't have any, it must be something else. Good luck!

Comment: Oh you mean no whitespace before the xml declaration in the file? Let me check.

Comment: No i have checked the file there is no whitespace before the `xml declaration`. Snif

Comment: @ExoticBirdsMerchant - Sorry...sometimes it's that easy. I'm sure someone will be able to help you out.

Comment: Thanks for contributing-hope someone will help me get out of htis